# Espresso freezing on view with looping animation

Tags: android, android-espresso

I have a view in which an element is animated with the following in an infinite loop:

```
<translate
    android:fromXDelta="0%"
    android:toXDelta="100%"
    android:duration="10000"
    android:repeatCount="-1"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"/>
```

When Espresso opens my activity, it's able to perform some operations but quickly freezes. I suppose Espresso is waiting for the UI thread to become idle which never happens in this case.

Is the only way for me to test this view to implement a mechanism to disable animations? I could have another class handle animations, which would be mocked for tests. Or build time conditionals.

Edit:
I have yet to create a sample project to attempt to recreate the issue, but here are some further details in the meantime:

1) I am using Jake Wharton's `ActivityRule` to have my activity automatically launched (https://gist.github.com/JakeWharton/1c2f2cadab2ddd97f9fb).

2) This is my test:

```
onView(withId(R.id.btn_yes)).perform(click());
```

3) Here is the complete stack trace. Note the `AppNotIdleException`:

```
Running tests
Test running started
android.support.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'single click' on view 'with id: com.myapp:id/btn_yes'.
at android.support.test.espresso.PerformException$Builder.build(PerformException.java:83)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.getUserFriendlyError(DefaultFailureHandler.java:70)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:53)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.runSynchronouslyOnUiThread(ViewInteraction.java:185)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.doPerform(ViewInteraction.java:115)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:87)
at com.myapp.espresso.MyActivityTest.yesButtonTest(MyActivityTest.java:53)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at com.myapp.espresso.ActivityRule$2.evaluate(ActivityRule.java:129)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:18)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:24)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:136)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:270)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1837)
Caused by: android.support.test.espresso.AppNotIdleException: Looped for 3580 iterations over 60 SECONDS. The following Idle Conditions failed .
at android.support.test.espresso.IdlingPolicy.handleTimeout(IdlingPolicy.java:61)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.loopUntil(UiControllerImpl.java:471)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.loopUntil(UiControllerImpl.java:402)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.injectMotionEvent(UiControllerImpl.java:226)
at android.support.test.espresso.action.MotionEvents.sendDown(MotionEvents.java:78)
at android.support.test.espresso.action.Tap.sendSingleTap(Tap.java:133)
at android.support.test.espresso.action.Tap.access$100(Tap.java:35)
at android.support.test.espresso.action.Tap$1.sendTap(Tap.java:40)
at android.support.test.espresso.action.GeneralClickAction.perform(GeneralClickAction.java:98)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.run(ViewInteraction.java:144)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

4) Stack traces when pausing the execution of the test while it's frozen:

Thread #1:

```
"Instr: android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner@4549" prio=5 waiting
  java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
     blocks Instr: android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner@4549
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-1)
      at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1220)
      - locked <0x13a3> (a java.lang.Object)
      at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:299)
      at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.awaitDone(FutureTask.java:400)
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:162)
      at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.runSynchronouslyOnUiThread(ViewInteraction.java:181)
      at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.doPerform(ViewInteraction.java:115)
      at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:87)
```

Thread #2:

```
"main@4663" prio=5 runnable
  java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
      at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.nSyncAndDrawFrame(ThreadedRenderer.java:-1)
      at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:333)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2492)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2337)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1968)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1054)
      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5779)
      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
      at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
      at android.support.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.loopUntil(UiControllerImpl.java:461)
      at android.support.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.loopUntil(UiControllerImpl.java:402)
      at android.support.test.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.injectMotionEvent(UiControllerImpl.java:226)
      at android.support.test.espresso.action.MotionEvents.sendDown(MotionEvents.java:78)
      at android.support.test.espresso.action.Tap.sendSingleTap(Tap.java:133)
      at android.support.test.espresso.action.Tap.access$100(Tap.java:35)
      at android.support.test.espresso.action.Tap$1.sendTap(Tap.java:40)
      at android.support.test.espresso.action.GeneralClickAction.perform(GeneralClickAction.java:98)
      at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.run(ViewInteraction.java:144)
      at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:-1)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: My understanding is that `MessageQueue` considers itself idle if no messages are ready *right now*, so an infinite animation shouldn't prevent that. I would profile your app with the `monitor` tool to see what else is going on on the main thread. Maybe some bad code is repeatedly scheduling itself with no delay.

Comment: UI thread is considered idle, if its message queue is empty, or its getWhen() - now() is less than 17ms. So an animation will block ui thread. Still what you describe doesn't fit the usual symptoms. If UI thread is not idle for 60 seconds, Espresso will fail the test with an exception telling so. @mieroy: Have you waited for this long? If you run your test in debug mode and break execution in debugger, what is the stack trace you get for the test execution thread and what is it for your app's main thread?

Comment: @haffax, I added to my question 3 stack traces: test runner & main threads during execution (point #4) and of the error after 60s (point #3). I must admit I don't understand well how animation events are scheduled and how the idle detection mechanism works.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, the problem you are having with the test is due to the animation.

The only solution I can think of is indeed to turn off the infinite animations.

In general it is a good idea to turn off animations when running functional tests, as they always introduce some flakiness.

**A bit of background:**

The UI thread is never idle from Espresso's perspective, because the message queue always contains an event that is scheduled for handling closer than the threshold used to determine if thread is idle.

When you look at [`QueueInterrogator`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/testing/+/android-support-test/espresso/core/src/main/java/android/support/test/espresso/base/QueueInterrogator.java), you can see that it's `determineQueueState()` returns `TASK_DUE_SOON` when message queue contains an event that is scheduled for handling in less than 16ms. [`UiController`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/testing/+/android-support-test/espresso/core/src/main/java/android/support/test/espresso/base/UiControllerImpl.java) will only continue execution when all idle conditions are fulfilled, in case of the `QueueInterrogator` this is only the case if the message queue is empty or the next message is scheduled for handling in 16ms or later.

Animations will invalidate the `View` they are transforming, and this will trigger a new view hierarchy traversal by the `Choreographer`. And this trigger message coming from `ViewRoot` to the `Choreographer` is what is keeping your UI thread message queue not idle.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed investigation. I came to the conclusion that this is true ;) Interestingly, changing my animations from using the Animation "framework" to the Animator one got rid of the issue. Now I have the inverse problem where I can't get Espresso to wait for some other (finite) animations to finish before carrying on with evaluations :) I still end up having to implement a way to disable animations for (Espresso) tests. Thanks!