# Espresso test error: AppNotIdleException

Tags: android, android-espresso, ui-testing

I turned off all animations on developer options.
But I still get this exception when trying to click on one of the buttons.

My app is indeed active and not idle entirely, but I can't change it.

```
android.support.test.espresso.AppNotIdleException: Looped for 6930
iterations over 60 SECONDS. The following Idle Conditions failed .
 at dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:580)
 at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.getUserFriendlyError(DefaultFailureHandler.java:92)
 at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:56)
 at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.runSynchronouslyOnUiThread(ViewInteraction.java:184)
 at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.doPerform(ViewInteraction.java:115)
 at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:87)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Espresso freezing on view with looping animation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29550508/espresso-freezing-on-view-with-looping-animation)

Comment: What do you mean by "app is active"? Are you doing some background thread operations or is this a progress indicator? Do you have a custom IdlingResource which returns an empty string in getName()?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40240310/3902106 you can refer to my answer on another thread.

Comment: You can also refer to my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38797738/espresso-appnotidleexception/40240310#40240310

Comment: See my answer to a very similar question (AppNotIdleException was thrown sometimes): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35460708/espresso-onview-inconsistent-performance/44920191#44920191

Answer (score 5):

I have been struggling with this problem for the last few days.
Here is a method that I used to identify "violators":

```
private void dumpThreads() {
    int activeCount = Thread.activeCount();
    Thread[] threads = new Thread[activeCount];
    Thread.enumerate(threads);
    for (Thread thread : threads) {
        System.err.println(thread.getName() + ": " + thread.getState());
        for (StackTraceElement stackTraceElement : thread.getStackTrace()) {
            System.err.println("\t" + stackTraceElement);
        }
    }
}
```

In my case, Facebook SDK was using the AsyncTask thread pool.

Comment: You can also pause the app (in debug mode) when it hangs and look at all the AsyncTasks that are in the 'RUNNING' state.

Comment: How did you deal with this issue? I have a similar problem that I believe is the FacebookInitProvider making a call that stalls and causes the exception but have been unable to find away to avoid the call being made.

Answer (score 2):

In my case this problem was happening with `AnimatedVectorDrawable` and caused by an `objectAnimator` that was set to repeat the animation infinitely (`android:repeatCount="infinite"`). .

The problem was also present only on older platform versions. Tests were perfectly working on Android 9 while the problem was reproducible on Android 5 and 6 (not sure about 7 and 8 at the moment).

I believe, the root cause of the problem is the same as for indeterminate progress bars ([covered in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33289152/progressbars-and-espresso)). However, I haven't found any nice solution, only workarounds.

One of the workarounds is to detect that the animation is turned off (animator duration is 0) in the setting and don't start the animation. Of course, this only works for platform versions where the animation does not autostart.

```
private fun startIconAnimation(imageView: ImageView) {
    if (areAnimationsEnabled()) {
        (imageView.drawable as Animatable).start()
    }
}

private fun areAnimationsEnabled(): Boolean {
    val animatorDurationScale = Settings.Global.getFloat(
        requireContext().contentResolver,
        Settings.Global.ANIMATOR_DURATION_SCALE,
        1.0f
    )
    return animatorDurationScale != 0.0f
}
```

Note: API level 26 introduced a static method `ValueAnimator.areAnimatorsEnabled()` which would have been handy if the problem was not happening only on the older platform versions.

Answer (score 1):

As per [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28074719/espresso-test-fails-after-successful-click-and-blocking-for-60-seconds/28076695#28076695) by [MaciejGórski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2183804/maciejg%C3%B3rski)  to the similar question:

> It was a bug in my app code, where `SwipeRefreshLayout` animated
>   itself indefinitely. Due to [a bug in this
>   component](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77712),
>   the refresh state was not even showing.

Comment: @Be_Negative yes, it has to go to its rightful owner. ~Arigato

Comment: @Be_Negative But I don't have any SwipeRefereshLayout or RecyclerView in my layout.

Comment: u can refer to this answer as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38797738/espresso-appnotidleexception/40240310#40240310

Answer (score 0):

In my case I clicked "save" button running long request in a test. To complete the test I had to add `idle()` after save() method. But often it was not enough, a loader continued drawing and the test failed. Then I increased a duration: `idle(10000)` and got the error: `androidx.test.espresso.AppNotIdleException: Looped for 238 iterations over 10 SECONDS. The following Idle Conditions failed DELAY_HAS_PAST.`.

I wrote: `idle(5000)`. Instead of Espresso I use Kakao and Kaspresso.